# looping through tweepy Directmessages to send response

Tags: python, loops, tweepy

Hi I am using tweepy to just go through my Direct Message with the goal to be able to loop through a DataFrame and be able to respond to all of my Direct Messages that way.

Here is what I have done so far.

- I was able to convert the list of DirectMessage Objects into a DataFrame with only relative data such as the text from the Direct Message the sender_id and created_timestamp.

Here is what I am stuck on.

- When I am looping through the sender_id column it is getting stuck on the most recent Direct Message the Direct Message in index position 0.
- What it is doing is just spamming test test until it is considered spam by twitter and it stops after a certain amount of test test sent.

Below is the code that I have to loop through sender_id

```
 for id in official_df['sender_id']:
    a = 0
    if id != my_id:

        if 'hello' in official_df['text'][a]:
            api.send_direct_message(official_df['sender_id'][a], 'test test')
            print('registration worked')


    a+=1
```

Comment: You dont get errors? It just hangs? Maybe you exceed the quota so the requests are rejected (Tweepy is able to wait - instead of throwing errors - how do you initialise the Tweepy session?)

Comment: What it does is just spams test test until twitter considers it spam